# Help me for create a xml, based on Room Count of hotel

Tags: xml, asp-classic

Help me for create a xml, based on Room Count of hotel

For example: 
I have 5 Rooms: Room1, Room2, Room3, Room4 and Room5.

```
In Room1: 2 Adults, 1 Child, Age 6
In Room2: 1 Adult, 0 Child
In Room3: 2 Adults, 2 Child, Age 6, Age 7
In Room4: 1 Adult, 0 Child
In Room5: 2 Adult, 1 Child, Age 6
```

1. If Child is 0 and Adult count comes same ( here the example adult count is 1), we take that rooms in one ( as 2 rooms). Other rooms in different .

> ```
> <%
> XMLLIST =”<Hotel>”&_
>       “<RoomList>”&_
>       “<Room>”&_
> “<RoomCount>2</RoomCount>”&_
> “<Adults>1</Adults>”&_
> “<Child>0</Child>”&_
>       “</Room>”&_
>
> “<Room>”&_
> “<RoomCount>1</RoomCount>”&_
> “<Adults>2</Adults>”&_
> “<Child>1</Child>”&_
> “<Age>6</Age>”&_
>       “</Room>”&_
> “<Room>”&_
> “<RoomCount>1</RoomCount>”&_
> “<Adults>2</Adults>”&_
> “<Child>2</Child>”&_
> “<Age>6</Age>”&_
> “<Age>7</Age>”&_
>       “</Room>”&_
> “<Room>”&_
> “<RoomCount>1</RoomCount>”&_
> “<Adults>2</Adults>”&_
> “<Child>1</Child>”&_
> “<Age>6</Age>”&_
>       “</Room>”&_
>       “</RoomList>”&_
>       “</Hotel>”
> %>
> ```

Plz help me to create a loop in asp code for create .

Comment: Please clairfy your question and reformat the xml source.

Comment: The Age tags seem to be missing an end tag and aren't inside the Child elements. (Btw, I reformatted your Q.)

Comment: tks now i changed to currect format

Comment: If you struggle with English then you need more words and examples to have any hope of being understood.  Currently this question makes no sense.  Add more description of what you are trying to do, add more examples of input data and desired output data, the more info the better guesses we can make about what your really want.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Gelatin](http://wiki.github.com/knipknap/Gelatin/) for converting text files to XML. (Note that what you posted isn't XML though.)